# SimpleXML and XML collections - how to get the attribute value as an array key?

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm just trying to figure out how to cleanly and nicely transform a XML collection into an appropriate object. See, I've got this very simple XML string :

```
$x = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<apiKeys>
    <apiKey application="app1">HfxaoMBJJ9pLe</apiKey>
    <apiKey application="app2">HfxaoMBJJ9pLeClsSHsh</apiKey>
    <apiKey application="app3">HfxaoMBJJ9pLeClsSHshTI9qX</apiKey>
</apiKeys>';
```

Which I transform using :

```
$O_xmlElement   = simplexml_load_string ($x);
```

This is what I get :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [apiKey] => Array
        (
            [0] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLe
            [1] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLeClsSHsh
            [2] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLeClsSHshTI9qX
        )

)
```

And I'd rather have (I expected !) something like :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [apiKey] => Array
        (
            ['app1'] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLe
            ['app2'] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLeClsSHsh
            ['app3'] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLeClsSHshTI9qX
        )

)
```

Thank you very much for your help people

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML won't do what you want automatically. You'll have to build the object yourself:

```
$O_xmlElement = simplexml_load_string($x);
$myObject = new stdClass();
foreach ($O_xmlElement->apiKey as $apiKey) {
    $key = (string) $apiKey['application'];
    $myObject->${key} = (string) $apiKey;
}
```

Refer to the [basic usage example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) in the PHP manual for good examples of dealing with child elements and attributes.

When getting attributes from a SimpleXMLElement, remember that each attribute will be a SimpleXMLElement and not a string. You'll want to explicitly cast each attribute to string before using it as an array key or object property name.

Comment: OK, I understood you can't do that "simply". That solution fits me just well !!! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do it exactly as you want it, but you can check out php.net's docs here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Basically the attributes can be found inside an object attached to each of the apiKey objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); 
$newArray = array(); 
$count=0;
foreach($xml as $value){ 
    $key= (string)($xml->apiKey[$count++]->attributes()->application);
    $newArray[$key] = $value[0]; 
} 
$newArray = array_map("trim", $newArray); 
print_r($newArray);
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Array
(
    [app1] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLe
    [app2] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLeClsSHsh
    [app3] => HfxaoMBJJ9pLeClsSHshTI9qX
)
```